# Set values of a pandas row at once using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I set the values of certain columns `items` for a given index `idx` of a dataframe `df` at once using a dictionary of with `items` as its keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#setup
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,4)), columns = list('abcd'))
d = {'a':1, 'd':2}

df.loc[1, d.keys()] = d.values()
```

**Output**

```
df
           a          b          c          d
0     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
1     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     2.0000
2     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
3     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked and I didn't get the warnings I get with iloc.

Comment: @Miladiouss Nice to help you! :D